# I want to highlight the series in-between the two touch points

Tags: charts, visualization, maui

I drawn a Line series using Syncfusion MAUI chart.
In this when I clicked on the series , It was considered as first click
Again I clicked , that was second click

I want to highlight series in between the two clicked points.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChartInteractionBehaviour"
              xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Charts"
             x:Class="ChartInteractionBehaviour.MainPage">
  
    <chart:SfCartesianChart>
            <chart:SfCartesianChart.BindingContext>
                <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
            </chart:SfCartesianChart.BindingContext>
        <chart:SfCartesianChart.XAxes>
            <chart:DateTimeAxis></chart:DateTimeAxis>
        </chart:SfCartesianChart.XAxes>
        
        <chart:SfCartesianChart.YAxes >
            <chart:NumericalAxis ></chart:NumericalAxis>
        </chart:SfCartesianChart.YAxes>

        <chart:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                          XBindingPath="Date"
                          YBindingPath="Amount"
                          ></chart:LineSeries>

            <chart:SfCartesianChart.InteractiveBehavior>
                <local:ChartInteractiveExt></local:ChartInteractiveExt>
            </chart:SfCartesianChart.InteractiveBehavior>
        
    </chart:SfCartesianChart>
       
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using Syncfusion.Maui.Charts;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ChartInteractionBehaviour
{
    public class ChartInteractiveExt : ChartInteractiveBehavior
    {

        private float firstClickX = float.NaN;
        private float firstClickY = float.NaN;
        private float secondClickX = float.NaN;
        private float secondClickY = float.NaN;

        protected override void OnTouchUp(ChartBase chart, float pointX, float pointY)
        {
            base.OnTouchUp(chart, pointX, pointY);

            if (float.IsNaN(firstClickX) || float.IsNaN(firstClickY))
            {
                firstClickX = pointX;
                firstClickY = pointY;
            }
            else if (float.IsNaN(secondClickX) || float.IsNaN(secondClickY))
            {
                
                secondClickX = pointX;
                secondClickY = pointY;

                if (chart is Syncfusion.Maui.Charts.SfCartesianChart cartesianChart)
                {
                    var pointX1 = cartesianChart.PointToValue(cartesianChart.XAxes[0],firstClickX,firstClickY);
                    var pointY1 = cartesianChart.PointToValue(cartesianChart.YAxes[0], firstClickX, firstClickY);
                    var pointX2 = cartesianChart.PointToValue(cartesianChart.XAxes[0], secondClickX, secondClickY);
                    var pointY2 = cartesianChart.PointToValue(cartesianChart.YAxes[0], secondClickX, secondClickY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output (Example)**

[image: Expected output (Example)]

Please provide an idea or code to achieve this

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/cartesian-charts/selection (You may also want to check out SelectionBehavior)